# How To Get Thursdays Of Year Using Carbon

Tags: laravel-5.1, php-carbon

I want to get all the Thursdays of a year using Carbon and save it on DB.

so far I could only store the Thursdays of current month. please advice me how to make it for the whole year once.

**Current code :**

```
public function getThursdays()
{
    return new \DatePeriod(
        Carbon::parse("first thursday of this month"),
        CarbonInterval::week(),
        Carbon::parse("first thursday of next month")
    );
}

public function handle()
{

    $thursdays = $this->getThursdays();

    foreach ($thursdays as $thursday)
    {
        $Weeks = new Week();
        $Weeks->week_starting_date   = $thursday;
        $Weeks->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the number of weeks per year firstly using `WEEKS_PER_YEAR`, e.g :

```
$weeks_per_year = Carbon::WEEKS_PER_YEAR;
```

After that get the first thursday of year using :

```
$first_thursday = Carbon::parse("first thursday of this year");
```

Then loop through all the weeks adding every time one week using Carbon function **addWeeks(1)** to get the thursday of the next week and so :

```
for($i=1;$i<$weeks_per_year;$i++)
{
    array_push( $thursdays, $first_thursday->addWeeks(1)->toDateString() );
}
```

**FULL code :**

```
$weeks_per_year = Carbon::WEEKS_PER_YEAR;
$first_thursday = Carbon::parse("first thursday of this year");

$thursdays = [$first_thursday->toDateString()];

for($i=1;$i<$weeks_per_year;$i++)
{
    array_push( $thursdays, $first_thursday->addWeeks(1)->toDateString() );
}
```

**Output :**

An array of all the year thursdays in following format `yyyy-mm-dd` :

```
["2016-01-07","2016-01-14","2016-01-21", ... ,"2016-12-29"]
```

Or you can store dates directely in you DB instead of returning an array like :

```
for($i=1; $i<$weeks_per_year;$i++){
    $Weeks = new Week();
    $Weeks->week_starting_date = $first_thursday->addWeeks(1)->toDateString();
    $Weeks->save();
}
```

Hope this helps.